# How to let a div fill the viewport with margins?

Tags: html, css

I'm studying the CSS units and box model. I'm looking for the simplest way to let a `div` fill the viewport (with some margins) using only plain CSS properties (no flexbox, grid) and without letting the `div` get larger than the viewport (no scrollbars).

```css
div {
  width: 95%;
  height: 95%;
  margin: auto auto;
  background-color: #128c7e;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with calc and vw, vh together.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  width: calc(100vw - 40px);
  height: calc(100vh - 40px);
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: teal;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Ok, I was thinking about `vw` and `vh`. Is `100vw` not equal to `100%` when `body` is the parent element for which I'm calculating the percentage?

Comment: No `viewport` is not equal `body`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vh` and `vw` for this:

`95vw` means that it will use 95% of the `viewport` width.

Look [here](https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/) for additional info.

```css
div { 
  width: 95vw;
  height: 95vh;
  margin: auto auto;
  background-color: #128c7e; 
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use viewport dimensions (vh & vw).

You can read more about it here: [Viewport units](https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/)

```css
div {
  width: 95vw;
  height: 95vh;
  margin: auto auto;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```